# Cannot create branch in Github

Tags: github, branch, git-branch

I am trying to create a branch on someone else's repo. I am trying to follow the official instructions, but I get stuck here because Github apparently should offer to create a branch when I type it in? But here, nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the right permissions? Can you type inside that "new branch" textfield? Why not doing it with the terminal?

Comment: I was not added as a collaborator for this repo. & I don't like the terminal tbh

Comment: Knew it. Your are welcome

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So I figured out what my problem was. I was not added as a collaborator for this repo. I did not know that I had to be a collaborator to make a new branch.

Comment: github is insanely complicated in the beginning, but eventually you'll get used to it.

don't forget to mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You just type something into the field and it should say "create branch: [name] from 'master'" or similar, below the input field. Click the blue box that appears and it will create a new branch.